# .PadLeft not properly inserting padding characters

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been attempting to write a piece of code for a file manifesting tool. I am attempting to use .PadLeft to shift the characters to replace the directory text.

```
int count = 0;
temp1.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(path));
foreach (string file in temp1)
{
    string temp = "\\";
    int padCount = (path.Length + file.Length + temp.Length + 1); //+1 because it counts temp as only one character.
    temp.PadLeft(padCount, '-');
    temp2.Add(temp + Path.GetFileName(temp1[count]));
    count++;
}
return temp2;
```

The input is a directory on the drive. The snippet above is part of the code that reads the files and puts them a in List<>.

Wanted Output

```
Z:\Documents
            \~~Manifest.txt
            \Anti-Tau.png
            \Anti-Tau.rosz
            \Army.png
```

Actual Output

```
Z:\Documents
\~~Manifest.txt
\Anti-Tau.png
\Anti-Tau.rosz
```

The output doesn't reflect that I am padding the left of the temp string. I have attempted changing the temp string, but that does not seem to do anything.

I have been watching VS2012's locals window and that seems to be the only thing that isn't working as intended.

Comment: Please show input and require output.

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI I added the input and the output that is desired. I also added what *actually* gets output.

Comment: Are you trying to print the list of files to a console with the padding?

Comment: @prospector No, it gets written to a list and some more things happen and then it gets printed to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the value back to temp:

```
temp = temp.PadLeft(padCount, '-');
```

Here is a complete working method:

```
public List<string> GetFileList(string path)
{   
    int count = 0;
    var temp1 = Directory.GetFiles(path);
    List<string> temp2 = new List<string>();

    foreach (string file in temp1)
    {
        string temp = "\\";
        int padCount = (path.Length + file.Length + temp.Length + 1); //+1 because it counts temp as only one character.
        temp = temp.PadLeft(padCount, '-');
        temp2.Add(temp + Path.GetFileName(temp1[count]));
        count++;
    }

    return temp2;
}
```

Comment: Is that really what I bloody missed? And... It was what I missed. Feel really stupid, I have no idea why I thought I didn't need to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the working method, I don't need it because I already had the entire program working, bar the padding. It is still useful for anyone else who needs it though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
            String path = "D:\\";
            List<String> temp1 = new List<string>();
            List<String> temp2 = new List<string>();
            temp1.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(path));
            Console.WriteLine(path);
            foreach (string file in temp1)
            {
                string temp = "\\";
                int padCount = path.Length+temp.Length;//(path.Length + file.Length + temp.Length + 1); //+1 because it counts temp as only one character.
                temp=temp.PadLeft(padCount, '-');
                temp2.Add(temp + Path.GetFileName(file));
                Console.WriteLine(temp + Path.GetFileName(file));
            }
```